# Laravel Collection where key/value equal

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-collection

I have a collection that I am passing to my view. There are 3 rows:

```
Collection {#869 ▼
#items: array:3 [▼
0 => Customer {#868 ▼
  #table: "customers"
  #guarded: []
  #connection: "mysql"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:10 [▼
    "id" => 17
    "business_id" => 1
    "first_name" => "Bob"
    "last_name" => null
    "email" => null
    "phone" => null
    "sent_at" => null
    "created_at" => "2017-10-03 16:18:30"
    "updated_at" => "2017-10-03 16:18:30"
    "deleted_at" => null
  ]
  #original: array:10 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
}
1 => Customer {#867 ▶}
2 => Customer {#866 ▶}
]
}
```

Out of these 3 customers 1 of them has a "sent_at" column that is null that I want to count within my view. I understand you can do this in the controller but I want to modify the collection in the view.

I have tried this in my view and it returns no results:

```
$customers_pending = $customers_all->where('sent_at', null);
$customers_pending->count();
dd($customers_pending);
```

I guess I'm not fully understanding collections and modifying them. $customers_pending should return = 1

I get:

```
Collection {#879 ▼
    #items: []
}
```

Comment: maybe it's not enough to find an answer... where is your controller?

Comment: @DanieleFois the controller doesn't really matter since I have dumped the customers collection in the view. I understand that I can modify the data in the controller first then pass it to the view but as I mentioned, I'm trying to do it in the view. Cheers

Comment: $filtered_collection = $collection->filter(function($item)
    {
        if(is_null($item->sent_at)
        {return true;}
 }); dd($filtered_collecton->count());

Comment: have you tried `whereStrict()`?

Comment: How about this way ....
$customers_pending = $customers_all->where('sent_at', null)->count();

Comment: @OmisakinOluwatobi yes, I get no results

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should add condition to your query, like this:

```
$customers_pending = Customer::whereNull('sent_at')->get();
return view('your.view')->with(compact('customers_pending');
```

because you don't want to get for example 1000 records from database to display only 2 in view.

But if you really need to do it in view, you can use they way you showed, for example if you need to loop over those customers you can do:

```
@foreach ($customers_all->whereStrict('sent_at', null) as $customer)
 {{ $customer->name }}
@endforeach
```

Be aware that when comparing to `null` it might be better to use `whereStrict` instead of `where` to get desired results

Comment: Understood. Something strange is happening. If I use my same code and change "sent_at" to "deleted_at" it returns all the customers since all of them have NULL in that column. Switch it back to "sent_at" and I get zero results.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you cannot modify variable in views using blade. The thing that you can do is the following:

```
@if($customer_all->count() > 0)
    There are {{ $customer_all->where('sent_at', null)->count() }} pending customers.
@endif
```

A dirty trick would be using the `@php` in your blade template:

```
@php
    $customer_pending = $customer_all->where('sent_at', null);
@endphp
```

than you can proceed using your new collection into the view.

Comment: Thanks for the php tip. Tried both and still get zero results even tho sent_at has null rows

Comment: Found out the issue. I had a model set attribute that modified the value to carbon so in the view it could not find the null value of 'sent_at' I feel like an idiot. I didn't think the model would change the data since I dumped it

Comment: Oh yeah got it, s*it happens my friend!